# Evaulate Javasript keyword error - RobotFramework -browser

Tags: javascript, browser, robotframework

I am getting error , when I am running Evaluate Javascript keyword in a RF browser library,
when I am running very same script in browser console, it works fine.
I also did try without semicolon at the end of line but didnt work neither , with another error
could anyone help? what I am doing wrong

```
Evaluate JavaScript    document.getElementsByClassName("dz-hidden-input")[0].style.visibility='visible';
```

```
Error: locator.evaluate: Unsupported token ";" while parsing selector "document.getElementsByClassName("dz-hidden-input")[0].style.visibility='visible';"
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "document.getElementsByClassName("dz-hidden-input")[0].style.visibility='visible';"
```

this element is set to hidden initially and in order to upload attachment I need to make it visible first, that what I am about to achieve

Comment: From the error, you're trying to use JavaScript code where some kind of "selector (a CSS selector?), not code, is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation you should pass two arguments, first locator and second JS function. Try this keyword:

```
Evaluate JavaScript    ${locator}    (elem) => elem.style.visibility='visible'
```

More examples: https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-browser/blob/main/atest/test/06_Examples/js_evaluation.robot

Comment: yes it works like this , didnt realize this change, comparing to seleniumlibrary and 'Execute Javascript' keyword, thanx a lot, much appreciated